# 429 error in VBA. Automated Row Removal Macro

Tags: excel, vba, activex

I recently had some macros crash after they were working for weeks. I opened Excel to "Automation Error Catastrophic Failure" Message. After doing some research here I found some information stating to delete some Temp .exd Files within the C:\users[USER]\appdata... This let me actually debug the code, but now I am getting a 429 error on code that worked last week. Last week I did add buttons (ActiveX buttons) to the sheet that reference the macro below, but it worked even after emailing to a colleague. I am confused and unable able to find answers. Also this code is my first real endeavor into coding so any and all information is welcome!

```
Dim workrange As Range
Dim Firstrow As Integer
Dim Lastrow As Integer
Dim lrow As Integer
Dim arr As String


'Find first and last used row in column S "Observation"
'This macro must be done each time you add new data
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("obs")
noObser = sht.ListObjects("noneed").DataBodyRange


Range("S:S").Select
Firstrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells(2).Row
Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("M1").Offset(Raw.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Row


'Loop through used cells backwards and delete if needed
For lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow + 1 Step -1
    Set workrange = Cells(lrow, 19)
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(workrange.Value, noObser, 0)) Then workrange.EntireRow.Delete

Next lrow

MsgBox "Extra Activity Removed"

End Sub
```

V2 of the code

```
Sub RemoveNoActivity()

Dim workrange As Range
Dim Firstrow As Integer
Dim Lastrow As Integer
Dim lrow As Integer
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim noObser As ListRows

'Find first and last used row in column S "Observation"
'This macro must be done each time you add new data
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Obs")
Set noObser = sht.ListObjects("noneed").DataBodyRange

Range("S:S").Select
Firstrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells(2).Row
Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("S1").End(xlUp).Row


'Loop through used cells backwards and delete if needed
For lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow + 1 Step -1
    Set workrange = Cells(lrow, 19)
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(workrange.Value, noObser, 0)) Then workrange.EntireRow.Delete

Next lrow

MsgBox "Extra Activity Removed"

End Sub
```

This is where I am at i have changed a bit thanks to BigBen, but I am still getting a 429 error at `set`

---

It turns out that the code was fine and that I had created a bunch of Excel Objects that were interfering with my object call. After more search the best solutions is to copy and paste your sheets into a fresh workbook and export your modules. 
[Image of the XL logo excel sheets i cannot delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yw99C.jpg)

Comment: What was Raw intended to represent? How many columns in the noneed table?

Comment: You're missing the `Set` before `noObser = sht.ListObjects...`

Comment: @Jeeped Raw is a sheet. It used to say sheet1, but I had a compiler error that sprouted earlier. After changing it to Raw I then received the type 429 Error. The compiler error higlighted the `.Rows` . The noneed table is a single column.

Comment: @BigBen I never had `Set` before and upon adding it I received the same error.

Comment: Yes - it won't fix the 429 error, but an error nonetheless - slowly picking away at issues. Did you mean to look at Column M instead of S when finding `LastRow`? Also there's no need to `Offset` down from `M1` only to then go back up with `End(xlUp)`

Comment: @BigBen gotcha I will add that in. You are correct I do not need column M just S. I apologize as I found this code and made it work for me from what I could make out with no background. I have add `Set noObser...`, removed `Dim arr As String` as I believe I am not using this. As well as removed `.Offset(Raw.Rows.Count - 1, 0)`. I am still getting the debugger highlighting that first `Set` with a 429 error.

Comment: If i comment out the two `Set` lines the code runs, and highlights the entire S column.